# Keyboard don´t work when home key is locked

Tags: android

I use [Android-HomeKey-Locker](https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker) to lock home key. It works, but if home is locked. Android keyboard never open and if I lock home when keyboard is opened keyboard don´t work.

Is there any way to fix this?

Block home in my application is strictly necessary and there is no other way to replace it.

Comment: Physical or Virtual Home Key?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same scenario in my current project, I have used the same [Home Key Locker](https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker) lib.

I have to take input in a dialog inside my Kiosk Mode activity, keyboard was not showing, so I do this:

```
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this.activity);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getHomeKeyLocker().unlock();     // Unlock before showing dialog

    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    final EditText edt = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.input);

    Button btnSubmit = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edt.setError(null);

            String tempString = edt.getText().toString();

            try {
                float value = Float.valueOf(tempString);
                if (value >= 10 && value <= 400) {
                    // Correct value entered
                    getHomeKeyLocker().lock(activity);  // Lock again after getting the value
                    d.dismiss();
                } else {
                    edt.setError("Enter correct value");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                edt.setError("Enter correct value");
            }
        }
    });

    d.show();
```

Basically, I just unlock the activity before showing the dialog and lock the activity again after getting the value.